# can we use windows 7 home edition to develop asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I am planning to buy a new laptop to learn asp.net web applications and also windows applications. Do we get IIS7 installed when we buy the home edition of windows 7 or should we buy windows 7 professional version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to learn, Visual Studio has a built in webserver for development that will work. If you want to deploy your web applications, [this page has information on which versions of Windows 7 have which IIS options available](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at some documentation on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx), it looks like all the Windows 7 Home editions (Starter, Basic, Premium) have the ability to install IIS, but it is not installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1495459/3537873.aspx), no problem found so far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IIS for ASP.NET Development if you use Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Express for the web is free, and comes with its own web server.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

You can also create windows programs with Visual Studio Express for windows.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

If you want to do both, then you may need to buy Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio can be expensive. He said he's learning, so he might qualify for an academic discount or through BizSpark or DreamSpark. If not, the Express editions have no problem being concurrently installed if he wants to do both web and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do local debugging of asp.net using IIS then you need one of these versions. Not supported on Windows 7 Home.

Windows 7 Ultimate
Windows 7 Professional
Windows 7 Enterprise

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3se23d.aspx